# Error writing at the base of firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to the firebase and I am making an app where you want to record two entities in one event. I want to record a user and a bakery, but I can not. The user writes all right, but in the bakery hour gives the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

The following code:

```
public class RegisterBakeryActivity extends CommonActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, DatabaseReference.CompletionListener{

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private Resources resources;
private EditText inputCorporateName, inputFantasyName, inputFone, inputEmail, inputCnpj, inputStreet, inputNumber, inputDiscrict, inputCity, inputAdminPassword;
private String corporateName, fantasyName, fone, email, cnpj, street, district, city, adminPassword, idString, numberString, cnpjAux;
private int number;
private static final String TAG = RegisterBakeryActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ProgressDialog progressDialog, pDialog;
// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_FANTASY = "fantasia";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "nome";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_STREET = "logradouro";
private static final String TAG_DISTRICT = "bairro";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "telefone";
private static final String TAG_NUMBER = "numero";
private static final String TAG_CITY = "municipio";
private String nameJson;
private String numberJson;
private String emailJson;
private String fantasyJson;
private String phoneJson;
private String streetJson;
private String districtJson;
private String cityJson;
private User user;
private Bakery bakery;
private Adress adress;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bakerieList;
private String code;
private String adressLocation = "";
private Location l;
private Double latitude, longitude;
private DatabaseReference mBakeriessNodeRef;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_bakery);
    callConnection();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    bakerieList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    resources = getResources();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    Button btnSearchByCNPJ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search_by_cnpj);
    btnSearchByCNPJ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cnpjAux = inputCnpj.getText().toString().trim();
            // Calling async task to get json
            new GetBakery().execute();
        }
    });

    Button btnAddBakery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_bakery);
    btnAddBakery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (validateFields()) {
                openProgressDialog("Cadastrando...", "Aguarde um momento!");
                initUser();
                initBakery();
                saveUser();
            }
        }
    });
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (firebaseUser == null || user.getId() != null) {
                return;
            }

            user.setId(firebaseUser.getUid());
            user.saveDB(RegisterBakeryActivity.this);
            bakery.saveDB(RegisterBakeryActivity.this);
        }
    };
    initViews();
    initWatchers();
}

/**
 * Chama o método para limpar erros
 *
 * @param s Editable
 */
private void callClearErrors(Editable s) {
    if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
        clearErrorFields(inputCorporateName);
    }
}

/**
 * Efetua a validação dos campos.Nesse caso, valida se os campos não estão vazios e se tem
 * tamanho permitido.
 * Nesse método você poderia colocar outros tipos de validações de acordo com a sua necessidade.
 *
 * @return boolean que indica se os campos foram validados com sucesso ou não
 */
private boolean validateFields() {
    corporateName = inputCorporateName.getText().toString().trim();
    email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    fantasyName = inputFantasyName.getText().toString().trim();
    fone = inputFone.getText().toString().trim();
    cnpj = inputCnpj.getText().toString().trim();
    street = inputStreet.getText().toString().trim();
    number = Integer.parseInt(inputNumber.getText().toString().trim());
    String numberAux = inputNumber.getText().toString().trim();
    district = inputDiscrict.getText().toString().trim();
    city = inputCity.getText().toString().trim();
    adminPassword = inputAdminPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    return (!isEmptyFields(email, fantasyName, fone, cnpj, street, district, numberAux, city, adminPassword) && hasSizeValid(fone, cnpj) && emailValid(email));
}

private boolean isEmptyFields(String email, String fantasyName, String fone, String cnpj, String street, String district, String number, String city, String adminPassword) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        inputEmail.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo email
        inputEmail.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_email_required));
        return true;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fantasyName)) {
        inputFantasyName.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo
        inputFantasyName.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_field_required));
        return true;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fone)) {
        inputFone.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo
        inputFone.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_field_required));
        return true;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cnpj)) {
        inputCnpj.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo
        inputCnpj.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_field_required));
        return true;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(street)) {
        inputStreet.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo
        inputStreet.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_field_required));
        return true;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(district)) {
        inputDiscrict.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo
        inputDiscrict.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_field_required));
        return true;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(number)) {
        inputNumber.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo
        inputNumber.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_field_required));
        return true;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(city)) {
        inputCity.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo
        inputCity.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_field_required));
        return true;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(adminPassword)) {
        inputAdminPassword.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo
        inputAdminPassword.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_field_required));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean hasSizeValid(String fone, String cnpj) {

    if (!(fone.length() > 11)) {
        inputFone.requestFocus();
        inputFone.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_fone_size_invalid));
        return false;
    } else if (!(cnpj.length() > 4)) {
        inputCnpj.requestFocus();
        inputCnpj.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_cnpj_size_invalid));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Limpa os ícones e as mensagens de erro dos campos desejados
 *
 * @param editTexts lista de campos do tipo EditText
 */
private void clearErrorFields(EditText... editTexts) {
    for (EditText editText : editTexts) {
        editText.setError(null);
    }
}

private boolean emailValid(String email) {

    String Expn = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
            + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
            + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
            + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
    if (email.matches(Expn) && email.length() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        inputEmail.requestFocus();
        inputEmail.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_email_char_invalid));
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class GetBakery extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        openProgressDialog("Buscando dados...", "Aguarde!");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        url = url + cnpjAux;
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject c = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                fantasyJson = c.optString(TAG_FANTASY);
                nameJson = c.optString(TAG_NAME);
                emailJson = c.optString(TAG_EMAIL);
                streetJson = c.optString(TAG_STREET);
                numberJson = c.optString(TAG_NUMBER);
                phoneJson = c.optString(TAG_PHONE);
                districtJson = c.optString(TAG_DISTRICT);
                cityJson = c.optString(TAG_CITY);

                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> bakery = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                bakery.put(TAG_FANTASY, fantasyJson);
                bakery.put(TAG_NAME, nameJson);
                bakery.put(TAG_EMAIL, emailJson);
                bakery.put(TAG_PHONE, phoneJson);
                bakery.put(TAG_CITY, cityJson);
                bakery.put(TAG_DISTRICT, districtJson);
                bakery.put(TAG_NUMBER, numberJson);
                bakery.put(TAG_STREET, streetJson);
                adressLocation = streetJson + ", " + numberJson;
                List<Address> list = new ArrayList<Address>();
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(RegisterBakeryActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                String error = "";

                try {
                    list = (ArrayList<Address>) geocoder.getFromLocationName(adressLocation, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error = "Network problem";
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error = "Illegal arguments";
                }

                if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                    Address a = list.get(0);
                    latitude = a.getLatitude();
                    longitude = a.getLongitude();
                } else {

                }

                // adding contact to contact list
                bakerieList.add(bakery);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        closeProgressDialog();
        setEditText(fantasyJson, nameJson, emailJson, streetJson, numberJson, districtJson, cityJson, phoneJson);
    }

}

private void setEditText(String fantasy, String name, String email, String street, String number, String district, String city, String phone) {
    inputDiscrict.setText(district);
    inputCity.setText(city);
    inputEmail.setText(email);
    inputFantasyName.setText(fantasy);
    inputFone.setText(phone);
    inputCorporateName.setText(name);
    inputStreet.setText(street);
    inputNumber.setText(number);
}

private synchronized void callConnection(){
    Log.i("LOG", "RegisterBakeryActivity.callConnection()");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i("LOG", "AddressLocationActivity.onConnected(" + bundle + ")");

    //l = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if(l != null){
        mLastLocation = l;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i("LOG", "AddressLocationActivity.onConnectionSuspended(" + i + ")");
}

@Override
protected void initViews() {
    inputCorporateName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_corporate_name);
    inputCorporateName.setKeyListener(null);
    inputFantasyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_fantasy_name);
    inputFone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_fone);
    MaskEditTextChangedListener maskFone = new MaskEditTextChangedListener("(##)####-####", inputFone);
    inputFone.addTextChangedListener(maskFone);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    inputCnpj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_cnpj);
    inputStreet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_street);
    inputNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_number);
    inputDiscrict = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_district);
    inputCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_city);
    inputAdminPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_admin_password);

}

@Override
protected void initUser() {
    user = new User();
    user.setName(fantasyName);
    user.setEmail(email);
    final Encryption cripto = Encryption.getInstance(adminPassword);
    user.setPassword(cripto.getEncryptPassword());
    user.setType(true);
    user.setSendNotification(true);
}

private void initBakery(){
    bakery = new Bakery();
    adress = new Adress(user.getId(), null, null, street, district, city, number, latitude, longitude, null);
    bakery.setEmail(email);
    bakery.setAdress(adress);
    bakery.setCnpj(cnpj);
    bakery.setCorporateName(corporateName);
    bakery.setFantasyName(fantasyName);
    bakery.setFone(fone);
    bakery.setUserID(user.getId());
}

private void initWatchers(){

    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            callClearErrors(s);
        }
    };
    inputCorporateName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    inputFantasyName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    inputFone.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    inputEmail.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    inputCnpj.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    inputStreet.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    inputNumber.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    inputDiscrict.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    inputCity.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    inputAdminPassword.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i("LOG", "AddressLocationActivity.onConnectionFailed(" + connectionResult + ")");
}

private void saveUser() {
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword()
    ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                closeProgressDialog();
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            showSnackbar(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    //bakery.saveDB(RegisterBakeryActivity.this);
    mAuth.signOut();
    showToast("Padaria registrada com sucesso!");
    closeProgressDialog();
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
}
```

}

Class User:

```
public class User {

private String id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
private String newPassword;
private boolean type;
private boolean sendNotification;
private String image;

public User() {
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setNameIfNull(String name) {
    if (this.name == null) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setEmailIfNull(String email) {
    if (this.email == null) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getNewPassword() {
    return newPassword;
}

public void setNewPassword(String newPassword) {
    this.newPassword = newPassword;
}

public boolean isType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(boolean type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public boolean isSendNotification() {
    return sendNotification;
}

public void setSendNotification(boolean sendNotification) {
    this.sendNotification = sendNotification;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public void saveDB(DatabaseReference.CompletionListener... completionListener) {
    DatabaseReference firebase = LibraryClass.getFirebase().child("users").child(getId());
    if (completionListener.length == 0) {
        setPassword(null);
        setId(null);
        firebase.setValue(this);
    } else {
        setPassword(null);
        setId(null);
        firebase.setValue(this, completionListener[0]);
    }
}
```

}

Class Bakery:

```
public class Bakery {

private String id;
private String userID;
private String corporateName;
private String fantasyName;
private String fone;
private String email;
private String cnpj;
private String bakeryImage;
private Adress adress;

public Bakery() {}

public Bakery(String id, String userID, String corporateName, String fantasyName, String fone,
              String email, String cnpj, String bakeryImage, Adress adress) {
    this.id = id;
    this.userID = userID;
    this.corporateName = corporateName;
    this.fantasyName = fantasyName;
    this.fone = fone;
    this.email = email;
    this.cnpj = cnpj;
    this.bakeryImage = bakeryImage;
    this.adress = adress;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getCorporateName() {
    return corporateName;
}

public void setCorporateName(String corporateName) {
    this.corporateName = corporateName;
}

public String getFantasyName() {
    return fantasyName;
}

public void setFantasyName(String fantasyName) {
    this.fantasyName = fantasyName;
}

public String getFone() {
    return fone;
}

public void setFone(String fone) {
    this.fone = fone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCnpj() {
    return cnpj;
}

public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
    this.cnpj = cnpj;
}

public String getBakeryImage() {
    return bakeryImage;
}

public void setBakeryImage(String bakeryImage) {
    this.bakeryImage = bakeryImage;
}

public Adress getAdress() {
    return adress;
}

public void setAdress(Adress adress) {
    this.adress = adress;
}

public void saveDB(DatabaseReference.CompletionListener... completionListener) {
    DatabaseReference firebase = LibraryClass.getFirebase().child("bakeries").child(getId());
    if (completionListener.length == 0) {
        firebase.setValue(this);
    } else {
        firebase.setValue(this, completionListener[0]);
    }
}
```

}

The error comes from this line:

```
bakery.saveDB(RegisterBakeryActivity.this);
```

Comment: You're not calling `baker.setId()` after you create a new bakery, which means that `getId()` returns `null` in `saveDB`. But Stack Overflow is a lousy mechanism for debugging such code. I recommend reading [this question on how to troubleshoot this yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void saveDB(Bakery bakery){  
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("bakeries").child(bakeryId).child("bakeries").setValue(bakery);
}
```